# How to check if a cell value is contained in another workbook + extras

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I need to check if every cell value in single column in wookbook 1 is contained in a column in workbook 2, then check the value of another related column in workbook 2, and if its "Success" then highlight the original cell value in the workbook 1.

I'm an absolute beginner at Excel 2007 so any advice is appreciated!

R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, quite a task for an absolute beginner, but here you go:

In Workbook 1, create an additional column to check your condition. This column can be on a seperate worksheet, if you like.

A is your single column of workbook 1. B is your condition-check column.

```
B1=MATCH(A1,[Workbook2.xlsm]Sheet1!C:C,0)
```

Not sure, if I understood you right, but if you have to do this check with two related columns:

```
B1=AND(MATCH(A1,[Workbook2.xlsm]Sheet1!C:C,0),MATCH(A1,[Workbook2.xlsm]Sheet1!D:D,0))
```

---

Then you need to setup conditional formatting for column A of Workbook 1 to create the dynamic highlighting.

Select the whole column A, then add an conditional format based on a formula. The formula you can use is `=B1`. When you lookup this conditional format the range which it is used on should be `$A:$A`.

That should be it.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the detailed description... I think may take some time to figure out!

The second check, the "success check" I mention is a boolean check, but with it being the text "Success" to mean true. It doesn't relate to the first sheet.

Comment: ah, ok, this would be then just something like (A1="SUCCESS"), BUT, A1 would need to be your related cell of the related column from worksheet2. I don't know the relation, so I can't provide you a more detailed answer.

Comment: I've solved my problem in a different way in the end.

Your code was very useful as it lead me to a web page that had some VBA macro code that was close enough for me to change into doing what I needed. Ultimately a different approach but the outcome is the same.

Comment: ok, no problem :) but next time, if you'd like a solution with VBA, just say so - I would always assume that a non-VBA solution is preferred, if not obvious or stated otherwise. By the way, it would be nice, if you'd post your solution, might help someone else too ;)